# Why can't we apply @ColumnTransformer to @Id (primary key) field?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I use Hibernate’s @ColumnTransformer to map an encrypted database column to an entity attribute.

```
@ColumnTransformer(
        read =  "pgp_sym_decrypt(refresh_token::bytea, 'mykey or obfuscated key from keystore')",
        write = "pgp_sym_encrypt(?, 'mykey or obfuscated key from keystore')"
)
@Column(name="refresh_token")
private String refreshToken;
```

I decided to use refresh token as primary key (is it bad idea?) and update table row with new access token.
But it will not work with encoded primary key.

Why can't we apply @ColumnTransformer to @Id (primary key) field?

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue from 2015 in the Hibernate issue tracker where this feature request was actively rejected: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9808

If I understand correctly, it makes updating and lazy loading *way* more complicated. Also, there seemed to be a lack of interest.